# How to record calls using php

Tags: php, asterisk, voip, telecommunication

I want to develop a web software to make calls and record calls . How can i achieve this using php ? Do i need to learn asterisk ? I am totally new to communication programming.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_

Answer (score 0):

You can't use php to record file.

Only thing you can do is ASK asterisk record,using AMI(control interface) or dialplan(special document which describe for asterisk what to do).

For more info you need read some asterisk book for beginner.